# Transfer large amount of data between android app & server app

Tags: java, android, networking, data-transfer

**Context**
I made a professional Android app, by that I mean it's not on Playstore and only use for one specific purpose. It's deployed on around 200 Samsung tablets and work pretty smoothly. To make it simple, it loads data (~300Kb JSON file) in the morning, then users do business stuff and by the end of the day give the devices back after transferring their daily data (~8Mb zip file). It works okay, but managing 200 hundreds people and data transfer over wi-fi is sometimes messy. By messy, I mean that Wi-Router, there's only one, sometimes shut off connection to some devices, and these ones have to wait & try again later. Also, we had to restrict connections on the router to 15 simultaneous connections to avoid CPU overload. It's a Fortinet FortiWifi 60D.

**The problem**
So like I said, they load a few data in the morning (~300Kb) but that's about to change, and now I'm asked to transfer nothing less than 150MB each morning, on each device.

**My question**
That's a whole lot of data, and I'm afraid Wi-fi isn't going to be my best option here. I say that because maybe connecting them to a computer and transfer through adb scripts might be faster. Do you have any architecture advices, or any procedures you think I should apply to my problem?

**More info**
The web application sending data to devices is not remote, so no Internet transfer, only local.

Comment: You may wish to edit your question and explain, in detail, what "is sometimes messy" means, and how you think that not using WiFi will somehow improve upon this. You might also explain what communication mechanism you wish to use (Bluetooth?) that is not WiFi and does not involve the Internet.

Comment: @CommonsWare There you go :)

Comment: Using `adb` pretty much requires getting the Android SDK set up, which will not be a lot of fun. And while `adb` is faster than it used to be, I suspect that it is still slower than WiFi, though perhaps without your router issues. I'm also unclear what a router has to do with the problem, as if this is all local, your users should be inside the network and not traversing a router. I would focus on fixing the network or finding ways of exchanging less data in your app, rather than trying to roll out `adb` to 200+ non-developers.